# How to configure mocha to find all test files recursively?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

How can I configure mocha to find all test files in my project directory and not only the test files at the `test` folder in the root directory?

currently, I'm using npm scripts in package.json:

```
"test": "mocha"
```

and running using the following command:

```
npm run test
```

Comment: How are you running mocha? Are you using a task runner, an npm script, or directly from the command line?

Comment: using npm script (`npm run test`)

Comment: Ok. So what is the 'test' script in your package.json, then? It sounds like its something like `mocha test` currrently. If so, you'll want to change it to a pattern like steve suggested.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To find all test files in your `src` directory, say, then you should be able to use a pattern like this:

`mocha "src/**/*.test.js"`

...and make sure your test files have a `.test.js` file extension so they differ from your other `.js` files.

*(Note the double quotes around the pattern)*

Comment: You actually don't need the double quotes here. Not that they hurt anything, though.

Comment: @Steve Holgado thanks, but I would like mocha to scan all project folders and execute found test files

Comment: You can change the pattern to be relative to Mocha, for example `mocha "./**/*.test.js"`, but you’ll need your test files to have a file extension that isn’t just `.js` so that your regular JavaScript files don’t get picked up.

Comment: @stripberger, if you don't quote the pattern, it will be interpreted by shell and will become analogous to src/*/*.test.js, since shells don't understand the meaning of **.

Comment: How can I use this configuration and Id like to be able to pass a path as a paramether when runing some tests, because I already have more than 10 files, and would like to execute all (npm run test), and somentimes execute just one test like npm tun test test/model/user, nowadays I'm using like this "mocha './test/**/*.test.js'"

Answer (score 8):

this works for me, finding all test files in all directories except the node_modules

```
mocha \"./{,!(node_modules)/**/}*.test.js\"
```

for clarification, this glop expression says:

Take all files which end with .test.js in the current directory - which is the root - or in any subdirectory of the current directory, regardless of depth, except for ones that exists in ./node_modules folder.

Comment: Add more explanation to you answer. Like explaining what each part of code does for the user.

Answer (score 0):

For me "test": "./src/**/*.test.js" was not working, I've to add escaped quotes in the directory pattern

```
{
 "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha \"./src/tests/**/*.test.js\""
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was testing this out and wanted to try to run only one of the test files(not it tests, but actual separate files) in the terminal using mocha, but can’t seem to come around it.

I attached a screenshot below for explanation.

What I want to do is have only my test for killer robot run and not the app test.

[VS code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNQLe.jpg)